# Using Maven Appassembler plugin, how to generate scripts in BaseDir?

Tags: maven, appassembler

I have a Maven project that uses Appassembler plugin to assemble the deployment. I want the generated SH and BAT scripts to be in the base directory and not in a specific folder (default being /bin).

I have tried setting binFolder to ${basedir} and ".",but both result in classpath errors when running the generated scripts.

My current plugin configuration is as follows:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                                                    <mainClass>myMainClass</mainClass>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                    <configurationSourceDirectory>src/main/resources/conf</configurationSourceDirectory>
                    <copyConfigurationDirectory>true</copyConfigurationDirectory>
                    <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                    <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
                    <binFolder>bin</binFolder>
                    <showConsoleWindow>true</showConsoleWindow>
                    <logsDirectory>log</logsDirectory>
                    <tempDirectory>temp</tempDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This configuration results in the following directory structure:

-appassembler
    -bin   <--- scripts generated here
    -etc
    -lib
    -log

What I want is:

-appassembler   <--- scripts generated here
    -bin
    -etc
    -lib
    -log

Comment: First why do you use such an old version https://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/ ?

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, thanks for you comment.I wasn't aware it was such an old version. When visiting https://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/index.html that's the version that shows up in the header bar. What version would you recommend using? Is there a link to the latest version documentation?

Comment: There seemed to be an issue on the page..I recommend to use the most recent version 2.1.0 ....

Comment: Thanks, I'll upgrade my POM files to the newer version. Any thoughts on the original question?

Comment: Do you have an example project?

Comment: The question applies to any Maven simple project, I believe. I have included the current plugin configuration, the resulting structure and the desired structure. To put it simply, I don't want a "bin" folder.